# Mysql query to PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select storeID, itemID, custID, sum(price)
from Sales F
group by storeID, custID, itemID 
    with cube(storeID, custID);
```

I am going to use this query in postgreSQL but it doesn't work in postgreSQL directly
how can I convert this query into postgreSQL query?

Comment: If think PostgreSQL's terminology uses ROLLUP instead of CUBE.

Comment: Your MySQL query is not valid: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9cacd340e8bb1d7def13be2ec01b909 What is the expected result

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work without the `with` keyword:

```
select storeID, itemID, custID, sum(price)
from Sales F
group by itemID, cube(storeID, custID);
```

I prefer grouping sets for expressing groupings:

```
select storeID, itemID, custID, sum(price)
from Sales F
group by grouping sets ( (storeID, custID, itemID),
                         (custID, itemID),
                         (storeID, itemID),
                         (itemID)
                       );
```

If I understand what you want to do, this should be exactly the same.

You could also use `cube` and then filter:

```
select storeID, itemID, custID, sum(price)
from Sales F
group by cube(storeID, custID, itemID)
having itemId is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select storeID, itemID, custID, sum(price)
from Sales F
group by cube (storeID, itemID, custID)
```

- Check [`this post`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cube/) for more details on `CUBE`,`GROUPING SETS` and `ROLLUP`.